# UISegmentedControl with UITableView

Tags: ios

I have the following views set up in IB for my project: `UITabBarView->UINavigationView->MyCustomViewController`.

I added a `UISegmentedControl` and a `UITableView` to the `CustomView` via IB by just dragging them onto the screen.  I would like my app to look very similar to the AppStore app.  Everything looks fine in IB; however, once it populates the `UITableView` with data, it covers the whole underlying view with a single cell (the segmented control is covered).

I didn't want to have to do everything in code so I've tried to stick with IB since this seems simple enough.  Does anyone know why my `UITableView` is taking up the whole frame?

Comment: Check that the resizing mask is set correctly on the table view. Also ensure that in IB you are telling the view to simulate the tab bar and navigation bar so that the content view is the right size and then if things look correct in IB, it should work fine when run.

Comment: What do you mean, it covers "the whole underlying view"?

Comment: The resizing mask looks correct. Here's what I did.  I created a new Tabbed app and enabled storyboards.  Added a new UIViewController with embedded NavigationController, added a UIToolBar at the bottom (above tabbar), added a UITableView by resizing the UITableView to fit between the Nav bar and toolbar.  I hardcoded the rows to 2 and drew a Default cell.

I ran the app and the UITableView fills in more than 2 cells (it expands all the way down).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on.  I was incorrectly re-sizing the table view cell when binding the data.  I ended up using the new prototype cells in the storyboard instead of trying to create a separate nib.